# mongoDB native node.js driver infinite reconnect attempts

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my tests I use the following node.js script:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.promisifyAll(mongo);

var mongoCollection;

function query() {
    mongoCollection.findAsync({}, { limit: 2 })
    .then(function (cursor) {
        return cursor.toArrayAsync();
    })
    .then(function (records) {
        console.log("got data");
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("promise error: " + e);
    });
}

function connect() {
    mongo.MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', {
        server: {
            auto_reconnect: true
        }
    })
    .then(function (db) {
        mongoCollection = db.collection("users");

        setInterval(function () {
            query();
        }, 2000);

        db.on('error', function () { 
            console.log("db error");
        });

    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log("connection error: " + e);
    });
}

connect();
```

It prints "got data" every 2 seconds until I shutdown mongoDB server. At this point, the driver tries to reconnect (auto_reconnect: true). However, it happens in infinite loop. Looking at driver source code, I see that in /lib/mongodb/connection/server.js, there is a function __attemptReconnect. It calls itself until the configured number of reconnect attempts have finished. After that, it emits "error" event. This event is caught at connection pool level. Connection pool resets re-connection attempts counter and calls this function again. And so on, and so on, until the server is up again.

It seems to be such a trivial use case. I want my db clients to get an error, if re-connection attempts haven't succeeded in few seconds. Is it possible without workaround solutions, using just proper settings? Am I just missing something? I know there are similar questions out there, but I haven't found any answer.

Comment: What version of the Node driver are you using?

Comment: The latest one, 1.4.30

Comment: Hi Konstantin, have you ever found a solution  to this problem? Maybe a way to receive the error event when the configured number of reconnect tries failed?